# How to force initiate a mongo replica when other replicas are not yet available

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to set up a simple mongo replication: One primary (mongo-01) and one secondary (mongo-02), both of which is running inside docker.

I bring up mongo-01 which I want as primary and within it, I run the below command as part of a shell script.

```
rs.initiate({
 _id: "replica-01",
 members: [
   {_id: 0, host: "mongo-01:27017"},
   {_id: 1, host: "mongo-02:27017"}
 ]
})"
```

I know for a fact that mongo-02 is not yet available (since i've not brought up the docker instance). The above command fails stating that "mongo-02" name or service unknown.

How do I force configure the mongo-01 instance to account for there beinga mongo-02 instance that is currently down/not reachable, and hence mark itself as PRIMARY and move on. Until at some point in time, mongo-02 comes up.

Comment: It's not just that the secondary is not available, it's the "domain" name cannot be resolved since there is no matching container yet.

Comment: A replica set with 2 members does not make much sense. If one of them goes down, then the majority is not available, thus no PRIMARY can be elected.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks. I understood that after a bit more of reading. We're looking to see if we need another data node / arbiter. But the premise of my problem doesn't yet change.

Comment: @AlexBlex - True, but is there no way for mongo to ignore the fact that the host isn't available?

Comment: Of course not. The purpose of initiation is to confirm replica set is configured properly, is healthy, handshake, elect primary.  How could it do all of it without actual nodes available? Check https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/03a8fabfea57bf6b496907467421559e68cf5d25/src/mongo/db/repl/replication_coordinator_impl.cpp#L4260 It checks quorum first thing after config validation